# Sylius - Entity variable value doesn't load in a form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, sylius

I decided to write a new feature to `Sylius`. Now, products has `availableOn` parameter, but in some situations (like selling tickets for concert,which takes place on particual day) also `availableTo` would be very usefull.
So I added variable to database

```
<field name="availableTo" column="available_to" type="datetime" nullable="true">
      <gedmo:versioned />
</field>
```

Added parameter to `Product` and `Variant` model as well,added to constructor

```
$this->availableTo = new \DateTime();
```

added method definitions to `ProductInterace` and `VariantInterface`.
Add label and widget to layout

```
{{ form_label(form.masterVariant.availableTo) }}
{{ form_widget(form.masterVariant.availableTo, {'label': false})}}
```

Add it to `VariantType` builder also:

```
->add('availableTo', 'datetime', array(
                'date_format' => 'y-M-d',
                'date_widget' => 'choice',
                'time_widget' => 'text',
                'label'       => 'sylius.form.product_variant.available_to'
            ))
```

And everything works fine except when I'm in editing mode the loaded value isn't from database (saving works ok, so I can type date, save and this is stored in database and displaying correctly in other views). There is a value 2010-01-01 without hours. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Did you try with `'date_format' => 'y-M-d H:i'` ?

Comment: @scoolnico Yes, it doesn't change loaded value - still 2010-01-01 00:00. Otherwise i copied this from availableOn code: `->add('availableOn', 'datetime', array(
                'date_format' => 'y-M-d',
                'date_widget' => 'choice',
                'time_widget' => 'text',
                'label'       => 'sylius.form.product_variant.available_on'
            ))`

Comment: And when you try to update, the right value of `availableOn` is displayed in the form input?

Comment: Yes and both values are correctly saving to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this problem was I didn't add this field in mapped-superclass in `Variant.orm.xml` file

```
<mapped-superclass name="Sylius\Component\Product\Model\Variant" table="sylius_product_variant">
      <field name="availableOn" column="available_on" type="datetime" nullable="true" />
      <field name="availableTo" column="available_to" type="datetime" nullable="true" />
</mapped-superclass>
```